# Lemur + PostgreSQL - can't render element of type

Tags: python, postgresql, pip, virtualenv

I'm trying to locally deploy a Netflix open project locally using the following documentation 
https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/lemur/latest/lemur.pdf (page 46)

and following these steps:

```
git clone git://github.com/netflix/lemur.git
# Create a python virtualenv
mkvirtualenv lemur
# Make the magic happen
make
```

When I call `lemur init` I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: (in table 'authorities', column 'options'): Compiler <sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.base.SQLiteTypeCompiler object at 0x10aaa3dd0> can't render element of type <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.JSON'>
```

I have a Postgres SQL server running locally (using docker) only address

```
postgresql://lemur:lemur@localhost:5432/lemur
```

But it's seems that the project fails to connect.
This is how I deployed to database docker:

```
docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_DB=lemur -e POSTGRES_USER=lemmr -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=lemur -p 5432:5432 -d postgres
```

**Working on Mac OS**

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was caused because a config file was not created, which by default caused Lemur to access SQlite.

Before calling 'lemur init' called 'lemur create_config', which resolved the issue.